# Fine-tuning BERT for custom NER

Tags: nlp, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model, huggingface

I have domain specific data in a pandas dataframe and I am attempting to fine-tune BERT-NER for classification task.

Here's my data:

```
from transformers import pipeline
import pandas as pd

# Load data
df = pd.DataFrame({'text': ["The income statement shows", "Total expenses for the quarter are", "Net income is positive."]})

# Use a pre-trained NER model to predict entity labels
ner_pipeline = pipeline("ner", model="dslim/bert-base-NER")
df['entities'] = df['text'].apply(lambda text: ner_pipeline(text))
```

This returns an empty list of entities as it is trained to recognize `[PER], [LOC]` entities and not custom tags like `[INC]` or `[EXP]`.

How do I prepare the data/annotate and fine-tune the model for custom tags / class labels following the `B-I-O` labeling scheme?

Answer (score 2):

Hi gather the data first. If you don't have one or want to add custom entities use an annotation tool like [Annotation tool](https://tecoholic.github.io/ner-annotator/).

After annotation convert the dataset into the format

```
#Tokenized sentences
['Hello', 'I' 'am' 'ABC']
#Tokenized entities
['O', 'O', 'O', 'PER']
```

After doing all this follow the basic tutorial on huggingFace website for [token classification](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/tasks/token_classification)

They teach you about fine tuning on custom dataset